# Protect Excel Worksheet for format and size and allow only for entry

Tags: excel

I am creating an XLS worksheet that would be used to collect data from the users. I have restricted the user input using validations. In order to easily be able to print the worksheet i have set the lenghts of the columns. Have made the relevant columns wrap.
However i would like to protect the worksheet such that
User is not allowed to
1. Change the format
2. Change the Validations
3. Change the column size
User should be allowed to
1. Enter input values
2. Select the value (from drop down whereever applicable)

The protect sheet always restricts user inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is *after* you protect the sheet to use the interface exposed in "Allow Users To Edit Ranges".  I'm going to assume you are using Office 2003 since you didn't specify, so you find it in **Tools -> Protection -> Allow Users to Edit Ranges**.
From there it should be pretty obvious - you create named ranges and give edit access to users based on that.
On the second issue of having users pick values from combo-boxes, you control that through **Data -> Validation** then create a Custom list.

Comment: Be aware that for Microsoft Excel for Mac 2011, making ANY part of a worksheet protected makes the ENTIRE worksheet read-only (makes EVERYTHING protected). As a result you are forced to remove protection and work with an unprotected sheet if you want to get anything done. I wish I didn't have to work on a Mac. POS.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/permission-issue-with-office-2007-file-in-excel/e5250f93-17bc-4542-9cbf-7a02d33e6481?tab=MoreHelp

Answer (score -1):

Normally when you protect a sheet you get a dialog box which allows you to select what users can and can't do.  If you select the right options you will be able to do what you want.

Have a look at [this blog post](http://all-e-courses.blogspot.com/2008/03/protect-worksheets.html) for more details.